# ASP MVC keeps auto logouting after some time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, timeout

I have ASP NET webpage and my login works like this:

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties()
    {
        IsPersistent = true,
    }, identity);

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    ...
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30),
    SlidingExpiration = true,
    ...
}
```

With this code, i can correctly log in. Problem is, that this will not log me in for 30 days, like i want to (even though identity cookie expiration is set to 30 days), but it only logs user for about a day, and than user is logouted, despite having the identity cookie still set (with expiration still 29 days left).

Any thought how to solve this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Haven't you got a policy installed on your computers that automatically empties your cookies every day or after a restart from the browser? It happened with us once.

Comment: No, i dont. It is not happeing only to me, but to all users using that webpage. And as I said, cookies are still set.

Comment: Is it a public website or an in-house website ? Policies are group based so it could be that this rule is applied on each machine. I am just asking :) Also are you sure you do not modify the cookie somewhere else too overwriting its settings ? Just for fun you could try this JS Cookie library to overwrite the cookie settings in the browser. So you could see if it is an ASP.NET or browser problem or not. 
https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie